# How to find values that don't belong to sample in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, sample

I need to take a sample from a dataframe but also I need the values that don't belong to that sample. For examle:

```
data = [[1,2,3,55], [1,2,34,5], [13,2,3,5], [1,2,32,5], [1,2,22,5]]
df = DataFrame(data=data, index=[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Output:

```
In[97]: df.sample(3)
Out[97]: 

    A  B   C   D
1   1  2  32   5
0   1  2   3  55
1  13  2   3   5
```

How can I reach the rest of 2 samples? Is there any basic way to do that?

Comment: Are the samples available at the same time as your data frame? If so, you should be able to just include them with that data frame.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are refering to. The samples are taken from dataframe which I wrote. @gustafbstrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With duplicates index it is problematic, so need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) firstly, then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) or [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
sam = df.sample(3)
print (sam)
   index  A  B   C   D
0      0  1  2   3  55
1      0  1  2  34   5
3      1  1  2  32   5

print ((df.eq(sam, 1)).all(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print ((df.isin(sam)).all(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print (df[~(df.isin(sam)).all(1)])
   index   A  B   C  D
2      1  13  2   3  5
4      1   1  2  22  5
```

Last reasign index back:

```
print (sam.set_index('index').rename_axis(None))
   A  B   C   D
0  1  2   3  55
0  1  2  34   5
1  1  2  32   5

print (df[~(df.isin(sam)).all(1)].set_index('index').rename_axis(None))
    A  B   C  D
1  13  2   3  5
1   1  2  22  5
```